# random circles using SimpleGraphics

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphics

I need to make a circle by adjusting conditions on the heights, this program using a lot of random circles but I am unsure where to go from here? I am trying to use the following equation d = (sqrt)((x1 –x2)^2 +(y1 – y2)^2). Right now the program draws many random circles, so adjusting the formula i should be able to manipulate it so that certain circles are red in the centre (like the japan flag).

```
# using the SimpleGraphics library
from SimpleGraphics import *

# use the random library to generate random numbers
import random

diameter = 15


##
# returns a valid colour based on the input coordinates
#
# @param x is an x-coordinate 
# @param y is a y-coordinate 
# @return a colour based on the input x,y values for the given flag
##
def define_colour(x,y):
##

if y < (((2.5 - 0)**2) + ((-0.5 - 0)**2)**(1/2)):
c = 'red'
else:
c = 'white'

return c


return None


# repeat until window is closed
while not closed():

# generate random x and y values 
x = random.randint(0, getWidth())
y = random.randint(0, getHeight())

# set colour for current circle
setFill( define_colour(x,y) )

# draw the current circle
ellipse(x, y, diameter, diameter)
```

Comment: Your `define_colour(x,y)` function doesn't make much sense. Can you explain what it's supposed to do? If you can't explain it in words, please give some typical inputs and expected output for each of those inputs.

Comment: @PM2Ring I need to make it so that I have a red circle in the middle and a white background. The program currently draws many random circles

Comment: It's still not clear what you're trying to do. Are you saying you only want to draw a single red circle centered at the center of the screen? If so, why do you have a loop endlessly drawing circles at random positions?

Comment: @PM2Ring no I am trying to make many circles the same colour, but only the random circles that appear in the centre. So all the random circles make a circle of a certain colour in the centre

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. You want circles near the centre of the screen to be red and all other circles to be white. So how close to the centre of the screen must a circle be in order for it to be red?

Comment: @PM2Ring what do you mean how close to the centre? the image needs to look like the japan flag.

Comment: But there's only a single circle on the flag of Japan! So why don't you fill the screen with white and plot a single red circle? I don't know the `SimpleGraphics` module, but surely it has a way to fill the screen, or a specific rectangle with a given colour. If you _really_ want to do this just using circles, then draw lots of random white circles and then finally draw the red circle at the centre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code that endlessly draws circles. Circles that are close to the centre of the screen will be drawn in red, all other circles will be drawn in white. Eventually, this will create an image similar to the flag of Japan, although the edge of the inner red "circle" will not be smooth.

I have not tested this code because I don't have the `SimpleGraphics` module, and I'm not having much success locating it via Google or pip.

```
from SimpleGraphics import *
import random

diameter = 15

width, height = getWidth(), getHeight()
cx, cy = width // 2, height // 2

# Adjust the multiplier (10) to control the size of the central red portion   
min_dist_squared = (10 * diameter) ** 2

def define_colour(x, y):
    #Calculate distance squared from screen centre
    r2 = (x - cx) ** 2 + (y - cy) ** 2
    if r2 <= min_dist_squared:
        return 'red'
    else:
        return 'white'

# repeat until window is closed
while not closed():
    # generate random x and y values 
    x = random.randrange(0, width)
    y = random.randrange(0, height)

    # set colour for current circle
    setFill(define_colour(x, y))

    # draw the current circle
    ellipse(x, y, diameter, diameter)
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! Any idea on how to make the circle bigger?